# Python Dateutil: Unable to calculate age from two dates (relativedelta)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-dateutil

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe, calculating a persons age using Dateutil's relativedelta function, using the following code;

```py
df['Age'] = relativedelta(df['Today'], df['DOB']).years
```

However, I'm getting the following errors;

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-f87ca88a2e3c> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df['Years of Age2'] = relativedelta(df['Today'], df['DOB']).years

C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __init__(self, dt1, dt2, years, months, days, leapdays, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds, year, month, day, weekday, yearday, nlyearday, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
    101                              "ambiguous and not currently supported.")
    102 
--> 103         if dt1 and dt2:
    104             # datetime is a subclass of date. So both must be date
    105             if not (isinstance(dt1, datetime.date) and

C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    953         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    954                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 955                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    956 
    957     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

It is successful outside a dataframe as below;

```py
DOB = datetime.date(1990,8,25)
Today = datetime.date.today()

relativedelta(Today, DOB).years

Out[2]: 29
```

=====================================================================

So i assume I am doing something wrong with passing in the datatypes to the function from the Dataframe?

I can calculate age a different way with the below code, I just don't understand why the first method isn't working.

```py
df['Years of Age'] = np.round((df['Today'] - df['DOB'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y'),decimals = 0)
```

Here is the starter code;

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta 


ind = 'Andy Brandy Cindy'

MyDict = {"DOB" : [ (datetime.date(1954,7,5)),
                    (datetime.date(1998,1,27)),
                    (datetime.date(2001,3,15)) ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=MyDict,index=ind.split())

df['Today'] = datetime.date.today()

df


        DOB         Today
Andy    1954-07-05  2019-08-30
Brandy  1998-01-27  2019-08-30
Cindy   2001-03-15  2019-08-30
```

Here is the calculation;

```py
df['Age'] = relativedelta(df['Today'], df['DOB']).years
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `relativedelta` can accept pandas Series as parameters. The traceback show that the problem is when you the code behind `relativedelta` tries to check the instance of the first parameter `dt1` passed to `relativedelta`, in your code being the Series `df['Today']`. Then is raised the value error from pandas saying that it is ambiguous to check if a Series is of instance `datetime.datetime` with `isinstance`. As you did yourself, outside of a dataframe, it works because you pass directly datetime objects and not Series. So you could use `apply` to calculate row-wise the difference between 2 datetime object

```
df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x['Today'], x['DOB']).years, axis=1)
```

but I think the workaround you found is faster, while maybe not as precise as using `relativedelta`

Comment: Thanks, so the 'apply' method would calculate row by row, whereas my alternative would calculate on the series? Edit: I realise now that I haven't rounded my alternative answer correctly.

Comment: @MysteRead indeed, the method you gave is vectorized and does the operation on the whole Series at once while `apply` does here the same function on each row. You are right that `round` is not the good method, doing `np.floor((df['Today'] - df['DOB'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y'))` would be more what you want. But then try both method after adding `df.loc['Ben',:] = [ datetime.date.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=10*365.2), datetime.date.today()]` this row to your example dataframe, this is what I was talking when I said not as precise, for some specific dates